# GRAVE: exception occurred while calling backend method java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, xml, maven, google-app-engine

I have a project in eclipse oxygen with google app engine standard maven where I have published some services rest and I use JDO (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2) to persist the non-sql database.

The code where I call everything is:

```
jdoconfig file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">

    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite"
            value="true" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns"
            value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName"
            value="true" />
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

code fragment in Java:

```
PersistenceManager mgr = null;
Cursor cursor = null;
List<Course> execute = null;

try {
    mgr = getPersistenceManager();
```

fragment pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes
    
        
            org.codehaus.mojo
            versions-maven-plugin
            2.3
            
                
                    compile
                    
                        display-dependency-updates
                        display-plugin-updates

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-m1</version>
        <configuration>
            <api>JDO</api>
            <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception you got means that the class you run has a parent class or extends an interface that has been modified since you started developing the code. All you have to do is modify the class you are using to run your code and re-run it with the new changes. You can find more information about this [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-how-to-resolve-incompatible-class-change-error/).

This may have to do with the warning you get from the link you attached in your question. It tells you that the DataNucleus plugin has been updated to use a newer version (from 2.x to 3.x), so you have to apply the related changes to your code to make it work.